# Is "who" used correctly in the sentence "Or he's a supernatural demon designed to torture people, who got offered his dream job"?

Tags: grammar

I was watching the TV series The Good Place when I came across this line:

> Or he's a supernatural demon designed to torture people,
> who got offered his dream job and has flipped on us like a ten-stone griddle-chip.

I have been taught "who" as a relative pronoun should be used right the person it's referring to. However in this case, the word ahead is "people", which confuses me.

I have looked into many online sources and could not find the explanation on this.

Comment: The phrase 'designed to torture people' describes the 'demon'. There is no rule that _who_ has to follow immediately after the name or noun indicating the person.

Comment: You've been taught incompletely. Relative clauses must follow the **noun phrase** they modify; if it happens to have modifiers following the head noun, then a non-restrictive relative clause follows them, as here.

Comment: Best to read it as: "Or he's a supernatural demon *[assume a comma here,]* designed to torture people, who got offered his dream job."

Comment: The comma is there to indicate that *who* does not modify *people*. Or you can read it like this: *Or he's a supernatural demon [who is] designed to torture people [and] who got offered his dream job and has flipped on us like a ten-stone griddle-chip.*

Comment: For instance, the order found in this sentence is not abnormal: "A man appeared who had a sinister red beard.".

Comment: All I question is the comma. It should be there since the relative clause is clearly restrictive, not non-restrictive, it saying "a demon," not "the demon." The phrase "designed to torture people" is an adjectival modifier of "demon." It's like writing, "Elizabeth I was a queen of England who never married." The restrictive relative clause that starts with "who" clearly  modifies "queen," not England. It's not England who never married but Queen Elizabeth I. It's like than writing, "That's a building John designed for us that got excluded from his portfolio," which is likewise not improper.